# How to get rid of a Bootstrap 4 navbar style

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

In this nice Bootstrap navbar with submenus, I would like to get rid of the light-grey background (#f8f9fa) that persists on the dropdown item when hovering the submenu.
That's probably a default bootstrap css but I can't find how to disable it.

Here's the codepen : https://codepen.io/surjithctly/pen/PJqKzQ

```
.dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu a::after {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  position: absolute;
  right: 6px;
  top: .8em;
}

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: .1rem;
  margin-right: .1rem;
}
```

Comment: I think you might need to use sass for best customization

Answer (score 0):

You may change this color to whatever you like by overriding the CSS this way:

```css
.dropdown-item:focus, .dropdown-item:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

In the example above, I set it to white.